# join files based on field with redundancy/missing values in field

Tags: join, field

I have two tab-delimited text files, and I’m looking to join based on a certain field (e.g., field1). In one of the files, there is redundancy in that field, e.g.:

```
field1  field2  field3
A   gene1   0.01
A   gene2   0.001
A   gene3   0.02
B   gene4   0.01
B   gene5   0.03
C   gene6   0.004
```

And in the other, there is no redundancy:

```
field1  name    pathway
A   A_name  A_pathway
B   B_name  B_pathway
C   C_name  C_pathway
D   D_name  D_pathway
E   E_name  E pathway
```

The second file also contains values in the field on which to join that are not present in the first file. Is it possible to join these files using the join command such that the resulting file will be:

```
field1  field2  field3  name    pathway
A   gene1   0.01    A_name  A_pathway
A   gene2   0.001   A_name  A_pathway
A   gene3   0.02    A_name  A_pathway
B   gene4   0.01    B_name  B_pathway
B   gene5   0.03    B_name  B_pathway
C   gene6   0.004   C_name  C_pathway
```

I tried looking at the man page for join and playing around a bit, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Do you have access to a SQL database?  How about R?  This would be easy to handle using either of these tools.

Comment: I have some experience with SQLite. Can I use that to join the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have some familiarity with SQLite, it might make the most sense to use this SQL tool to handle your problem.  First, import your two CSV files into SQLite using the following:

```
sqlite> create table table1 (field1 text, field2 text, field3 real);
sqlite> .separator "\t"
sqlite> .import table1.csv table1
```

And do the same for the second table:

```
sqlite> create table table2 (field1 text, name text, pathway text);
sqlite> .separator "\t"
sqlite> .import table2.csv table2
```

Now that your data is in SQLite, you can do the following simple join to get the result set you want:

```
SELECT t1.field1,
       t1.field2,
       t1.field3,
       t2.name,
       t2.pathway
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
```